# Non greedy match does not work

Tags: php, regex

I want to implement non greedy match using `.*?` pattern. However, I came across one sample string which shows, that non greedy match does not work. This is the code and the sample string:

```
preg_match_all('/\<w:t.*?\>\<w:p\>/', '<w:t xml:space="preserve"></w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:b/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">Text 1 </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:b/><w:u w:val="single"/><w:color w:val="ff0000"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"></w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:b/><w:u w:val="single"/><w:color w:val="ff0000"/><w:i/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">Text 2</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve"></w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve"></w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve"></w:t></w:r></w:p></w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidRDefault="004D3323" w:rsidP="003F03B1"><w:r><w:t><w:p>', $match);
```

But if I `print_r` the `$match` variable, I see that this pattern matches the whole string. However, what I want is to match only such strings as:

```
"<w:t><w:p>" and "<w:t any text may go here><w:p>"
```

So, what I did wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: I cannot stand those downvoters who prefer to stay secret and calm

Comment: There is only one `<w:p>` in your string. Also `<` and `>` are not special characters so they don't need to be escaped.

Comment: The reason the entire string matches it because the regex is built in that manner. If you look at the entire string you start with `<w:t` and end with `><w:p>` The regex is matching correctly, and is identifying the vast bulk of the string as part of the tag.

Comment: @Mari M. Thanks for sharing thoughts! But how should I write my regular expression, so that it would not match this very string and would match just pairs of `<w:t ...><w:p>`?

Comment: There is no `<w:t ...><w:p>` pair in this string. Is there suppose to be a match here?

Comment: @chris85. No. I suppose it not to match

Comment: I need to match only consecutive pairs of `<w:t ...><w:p>`

Comment: You should use a parser then. Matching nested elements is going to be a pain/unreliable with regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex instead:

```
<w:t[^>]*><w:p>
```

`[^>]*` allows all characters except `>`

see https://regex101.com/r/nuMzTk/1

Comment: You don't need the backslashes for `\<w:p\>` I believe. It can just be `<w:p>`